# How do I post code to be run on the Android main thread from a separate thread in C++?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a separate thread running in C++ in the background and I want it to be able to post code to be run on another thread that's already running an android.os.Looper (e.g. the main thread). By 'post', I mean something akin to `View#post` where a `Runnable` is enqueued to be run on the event loop. The code that would be executed is also written in C++.

I found the ALooper API (http://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___looper.html), but the docs aren't great and it's unclear to me whether getting the ALooper associated with the destination thread, adding another FD, and signaling it will make my code maintain correct ordering in the event queue with respect to the other enqueued Runnables.

I'd prefer not to have to go through Java and get a Handler, etc. -- it just seems unnecessary since both the code I'm trying to run and the code that's posting it are in c++.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain better "to be able to post code to be run on another thread" ?

Comment: this has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808206/android-jni-call-function-on-android-ui-thread-from-c

Answer (score 3):

A thread can only have one Looper associated with it, a Looper has only one message queue, so mixing Java and native callbacks will maintain ordering.

With that, I don't think there is any contractual obligation in Android today that `post()` is guaranteed to execute in particular order, i.e.

```
getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setText("first");
    }
});
getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setText("second");
    }
});
```

is not formally guaranteed to leave **mTextView** displaying *second*. Definitely nothing is set in stone when two **post**s are issued from different threads, or delayed.

You can find an [Android messaging and concurrency framework for native code development](https://github.com/Himmele/My-Blog-Repository/tree/master/Google%20Android/Android%20Messaging%20and%20Concurrency) desctibed in a great [blog post](http://himmele.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/android-messaging-and-concurrency-for.html).

## Update

Here is the required proof. The stacktrace below was received while working on an unrelated problem:

```
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 0000484c  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003031  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 002441f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+68)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 002285a1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+144)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000afe9b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+582)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b05d1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b299d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(bool, char const*, ...) (.constprop.129)+672)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bab87  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+50)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 00060817  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 000a5b29  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 00010fd7  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+482)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 00011081  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 0007fbe5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #13 pc 00051b8b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5411)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:916)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
```

Comment: The ALooper APIs in c++ do not involve a MessageQueue afaict. The case where two `posts` from Java (without delays) are called from the same thread does have guaranteed ordering.

Comment: Where did you find the formal guarantee of ordering?

Comment: ALooper is nothing but a thin wrapper around the android::os::Looper class, which does own an android::os::MessageLoop. You can judge yourself by the sources for system **libutils.so** in [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libutils/) (note that it recently moved to system/core from frameworks/native).

Comment: ALooper is not a thin wrapper around android.os.Looper, it's just really poorly named. Ordering guarantees I figured out from reading the code.

Comment: Please check the [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/native/android/looper.cpp#29) in AOSP. Just one clarification: not of the Java class **android.os.Looper**, but of the C++ class **android::os::Looper**, which is used, among others, by SurfaceFlinger.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function already executed in the main thread. If you call `ALooper_forThread()` or `ALooper_prepare()` there, you will get a pointer to looper associated with main thread. Remember to call `ALooper_acquire()` so it can be shared among different threads.

Comment: The main thread is special, it is guaranteed to have a Looper when your JNI library is loaded. Therefore, it's enough to call `pipe2(messagePipe, O_NONBLOCK | O_CLOEXEC);
 ALooper_addFd(ALooper_forThread(), messagePipe[0], 0, ALOOPER_EVENT_INPUT, handler, this);` with `int handler(int fd, int, void* data)` that reads from **fd** (it's easier to use same size messages), and chooses a callback to be executed on the UI thread. The *native version of Handler.sendEmptyMessage()* could then be as simple `write(messagePipe[1], &what, 4)`.

Comment: Why use a pipe and not an event file descriptor

Answer (score 0):

This could help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/v2OITtaZTes

But it is easy to achieve through  a handler on the java side, sending and processing messages doing back and forth between native and java with jni calls.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go through Java, as **`android.os.Looper` is not implemented in native code** (at least in [the currently most recent commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/78d5f90d98365987937b680862c4d88f3beaa4a3/core/java/android/os/Looper.java)).

I have not enough experience with the NDK to quickly type the required boilerplate, but the obvious option seems to be creating a java `Runnable` based on native code and sending it to the looper.

The not-so-obvious solution is directly operating on the `MessageQueue` of the thread. Once you have a reference of that, you can register one end of a native pipe there, and write messages to the other end; the pipe basically takes the function of a `Handler`, but on native code. Technically, your code is still called from Java, but you won't need the overhead. I haven't found much documentation on the whole thing, but [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/126nzj4sk7/native-looper-and-custom-messages) might be a good starting point.¹

However, it is perfectly possible that your code does not actually have to be called from the main thread, or that there is another option to solve your problem without going through Java. That would, however, depend on the problem you're trying to solve.

---

Note: I assume the main thread scenario. If you can use a native-code-based looper in the thread you want to deploy, you have more options.

¹ It is possible that the `ALooper` could be used in some sort of client-mode to do that, as well. Very unsure about that.

Comment: You are right, **android.os.Looper** does not use native methods, but the system library **libutils.so** contains native classes **android::os::Looper** and **android::os::MessageLoop**. The NDK ALooper API is implemented through these classes (see [comments in the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/include/utils/Looper.h#30)). These are used for example, in **libgui.so** which is responsible, among others, for the [SurfaceFlinger](http://www.slideshare.net/BinChen3/android-graphic-system-surface-flinger-patternsperspective-external-version).

Comment: @AlexCohn the OP specified that `android.os.Looper` is used. Has it been clarified somewhere that `android::os::Looper` is an option? If so, I missed that - this is what I intended to express with "If you can use a native-code-based looper", but maybe that wasn't clear enough?

Comment: Can you think of an experiment that could prove that ALooper cannot be used to post callables to the UI thread?

Comment: @AlexCohn Thinking of it again, I'm no longer sure that the `Runnable` is the best solution - albeit likely the easiest one. If one could get the `MessageQueue` behind the Java-Looper from C++ (might be possible, haven't looked into that), then the C++-Code could register there and be called from the `Looper`. Technically, it would still go through Java, but one would no longer need to handle the boilerplate around that, and might gain some performance.

Comment: re-reading Dianne's post, I believe that ALooper is safe. Native Activity uses ALooper to handle its lifecycle. Native Activity does have some Java code behind it. You can even *extend* Native Activity, and it continues to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some stuffs in the main thread from another thread, I suggest you to use the **runOnUiThread** function. The main thread in Android is the User Interface thread. I'm not sure if you can use this function in the ndk code.

An example of code could be this:

> > private void runOnMainThread() {
> >
> > ```
> > runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){       
> >    public void run() {            
> >    try {
> >        // do some stuffs
> >    } catch (final Exception ex) {
> >        // handle the possible exception           
> >    }      
> > }         });   }
> > ```

Anyway I suggest you to read the follow links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013585/using-ndk-from-c-updating-android-ui), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254523/android-runonuithread-explanation).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21015704/192373) some while ago!